# При выборе select изменить текст div

Tags: javascript

Делаю так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function selectChanged() {
            var sel = document.getElementById('myselect');
            var str = sel.selectedIndex ? (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].innerHTML + '') : 'Цена: 111';
            document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = str;
         }
</script>

<select name="city" id="myselect" onchange="javascript:selectChanged();">
         <option value="Цена:111">Котел 1</option>
         <option value="Цена:222">Котел 2</option>
         <option value="Цена:333">Котел 3</option>
         <option value="Цена:444">Котел 3</option>
</select>
<div id="mydiv">Цена: 111</div>
```

Но при выборе нужного элемента в диве вместо значение `value` отображается название, то есть Котел 1, Котел 2, Котел 3...

Что не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Много лишнего. Так будет правильнее:

```
<select name="city" id="myselect">
     <option value="111">Котел 1</option>
     <option value="222">Котел 2</option>
     <option value="333">Котел 3</option>
     <option value="444">Котел 3</option>
</select>
<div id="mydiv">Цена: 111</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myselect").addEventListener("change", function(){
      document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "Цена: "+this.value;   
    });
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oLotraa2/)

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!